# Windows Server 2008r2 process scheduling

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

We are needing a server that is solely responsible for executing various data manipulation scripts based on different events or triggers - previously when we were using Debian linux we scheduled it all with cron jobs. Is the windows task scheduler as robust as cron jobs? If not what alternatives are there. We use MySQL not MSSQL so their task scheduler is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Windows' Task Scheduler is perfectly fine for the job of scheduling tasks; of course, what the tasks can actually do depends on the programs/scripts/commands you ask it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Task Scheduler works just fine. GUI or cmd-line, too. And if you're really tied to GNU cron, you can install Cygwin.

If you have to do complex things (that even cron can't handle), you'll need 3rd-party commercial software. I mean things like handling multiple simultaneous runs, throttling, multiple machines, workflows - you'll need something expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Windows Task Scheduler.  It has evolved significantly over the years and now supports event triggers such as
 - time,
 - logon/off, 
 - user connect/disconnect
 -  workstation lock/unlock
 - system startup/idle
 - particular Windows event log items